# Get lon/lat of feature in PostGIS

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, mapserver

I have a point layer (shapefile) insert to PostGIS. I'm using MapServer and OpenLayers to display layer on map. Now, I want get lon/lat of all features of the layer.

Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Please clarify your answer. Do you want to get the points in PostGIS or on the web using openlayers ?

Answer (score 5):

To extract lon/lat in text format from a database table, you can do something like:

```
SELECT ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom) FROM yourgeospatialtable;
```

Where `geom` is the spatially enabled column.

There probably is also an OpenLayers function to do that, but I am not exactly sure where you want to do it (server/client?)